# complete flow of a magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, layout, template, products-management

I want to know the complete flow of a magento view. Suppose i am viewing the home page, can I ask how the flow of control goes through the **PHTML**, **XML** and **PHP** files , in order to view the home page? Basically wanted to know the flow of control of magento.Here which are the file which is considered as **Controller**?

Comment: http://blog.belvg.com/magento-request-flow.html

Comment: Hey @FabianBlechschmidt could you add your link as answer so OP can close the answer? Ff he feels the link covered it, which I think it did :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to http://blog.belvg.com/magento-request-flow.html it is already documented.

[image: Magento flow]